# Prove an assertion on infinite quadratic variation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

If $f$ is a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ which has the following property:

$\forall M >0$, $\forall p \in Q\cap[0,1)$, $\exists q \in Q\cap[0,1]$ and $q > p$ such that $|f(p) - f(q)| > M\sqrt{|p-q|}$.

Is it possible to prove that $f$ has infinite quadratic variation? i.e.

\begin{align}
\sup_{\Delta \in S} QV^{\Delta}(f) = +\infty
\end{align}

where $S = \{(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) :  0 =a_1 < a_2 < \cdots  <a_n =1, a_i\in Q \cap[0,1]\}$ and $QV^{\Delta}(f)$ is defined by $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|f(a_{i+1}) - f(a_i)|^2$ for $\Delta = (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) $

I have this question when wondering if it's possible to prove that the standard Brownian motion $B_t$ almost surely has infinite quadratic variation merely with the fact that $\limsup_{t \to 0} \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}} = +\infty$ almost surely.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for pointing out the error in my 'proof'. I think this is a counterexample to your claim:

Take the function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x)=\cases{{1\over \ln {((1-x)/2)}},&$0\leq x< 1$\cr \strut0, &$x=1$}.$$

Then this is a continuous decreasing function on $[0,1]$ and therefore has bounded quadratic variation (which in fact equals $0$).

On the other hand, $f$ isn't $(1/2)$-Hoelder continuous, with the 'problem' near $1$. So your condition holds.

See this page (I have done a few transformations so that the function meets your criteria exactly):

[Uniform continuous and not Hölder continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144280/uniform-continuous-and-not-holder-continuous/144292#144292)

Comment: Thanks for replying to my precedent comment. Here I still have a question. The given function $f$ is differentiable at $x \neq 1$, which means $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(x+h) - f(x)|}{\sqrt{|h|}} = 0, \forall x\neq 1$. So for such $x$ and large $M$ we can't find $y$ such that $\frac{|f(y) - f(x)|}{\sqrt{|y-x|}} > M$

Comment: The limit is equal to $\frac{f(1) - f(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}$, thus finite, isn't it?