# Proving that this limit is zero

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that if $f(0)=0$, then there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(f(x))^n}{|x|}=0$$
Here $n$ denotes a power, not a derivative. My first though was to use Taylor series, but I do not know if my fucntion is differentiable. I do not have any clue on what other thing could work. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How do you plan to use Taylor series with a function about which all you know is that it is continuous?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos good point

Comment: Something like $1/\ln(|x|)$ for $x \ne 0$ should work as a counterexample.

Comment: @MartinR but that function is not continuous, right? I am not only asking for it to be continuous at $0$, but in all of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Only the behavior near $x=0$ is relevant, you can easily make it continous on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: You're essentially asking whether continuity implies local [Hölder continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) (at $0$). The usual counterexample is the one Martin R gives. It's also discussed eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/144292/473276).

Answer (score 3):

A counterexample: Using the fact that
$$
 \lim_{x \to 0} |x| \cdot (\ln(|x|))^n  = 0
$$
for all $n > 0$ one can see that the function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined as
$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{ if } x = 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\log(1/|x|)}& \text{ if } 0 < |x| < 1/e \\
 1 & \text{ if } |x| > 1/e \\
\end{cases}
$$
is continuous with
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(f(x))^n}{|x|}=\infty
$$
for all $n > 0$.