If $f$ is continuous at a point, is it Lipshitz of order $\alpha>0$?
I am trying to prove a statement and my proof would be complete if I can prove the following statement:

If $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $f(0)=0$, then $|f(x)|<|x|^\alpha $ for some $\alpha>0$ in some open interval near $0$.

Upon reflection, this would be true if, more generally, continuity at a point implies $f$ is Lipshitz of order $\alpha>0$ at that point. Spivak defined this as

A function is called Lipschitz of order $\alpha$ at $x$ if there is a constant $C>0$ for which $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|^{\alpha}$ for all $y$ in an open interval containing $x$.

and also has the reader prove that if $f$ is Lipschitz of order $\alpha > 0$ at $x$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$. My question is, is the converse true, and if so, how should one go about proving it? I am looking for helpful hints rather than a complete solution.

its not true. There are continuous functions that are worse than holder/lipschitz

Unfortunately this is not true, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144280/a-uniform-continuous-function-which-is-not-h%C3%B6lder-continuous

@GhostAmarth my question has been answered by the links mentioned. Should I delete this?

In fact, most continuous functions in the sense of Baire category (sup norm) do not even satisfy a pointwise Lipschitz/Holder condition at any point. Moreover, "Lipschitz/Holder" can be replaced with any specified-in-advance modulus of continuity function.

The links provided by the comments provide a simple counterexample. Here I hope to give a natural path to the counterexample.
Every continuous function on some neighbourhood has a modulus of continuity $\omega$ such that
$|f(x)-f(y)| \le \omega(|x-y|)$. So the question asks if every modulus of continuity is of the Lipschitz type, i.e.
if $\omega(h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$, is it true that $\omega(h) \le C|h|^\alpha$ for some $\alpha,C>0$?
By considering $s=1/h\to\infty$ this is precisely the same as asking if polynomial growth functions are the slowest functions that grow to infinity: if $b(s)=1/\omega(h)$ is a positive function with $b(s)\to\infty$ as $s\to\infty$, must it satisfy $Cs^\alpha \le b(s)$ for some $\alpha, C>0$?
The answer is of course no, since logarithms grow slower than polynomials. For example you can take $b(s) = \log(4+s)$ or  $b(s) = \log(4+\log(4+s))$. Or for large $s$  just $b(s) = \log s$, or $\log\log\log\log s$, etc. Now undo the substitution $\omega(h) = 1/b(1/h)$ and you get the counterexample in the links.

Thank you. This was very illuminating and intuitively satisfying.
